# DOS batch script to open file explorer

Tags: batch

I wrote a script that you can use to open the file explorer from command line like

`e db` --> opens my Dropbox folder (`e.cmd` is the name of the script)
`e bin` --> opens my script folder

(I’m not very happy with the way I define the relationship mnemonic <--> folder.)
Remarks, anyone?

```
@ECHO OFF

SET "target=%~1"

if "%target%" EQU "" (
    ECHO No target specified.
    EXIT /B
)

SET folder=""
CALL :set_folder_%target% 2> nul
if %folder% EQU "" (
    ECHO Invalid target %target%.
    EXIT /B
)

explorer %folder%
EXIT /B

:set_folder_db
SET folder="D:\Alex\Dropbox" & EXIT /B

:set_folder_bin
SET folder="D:\Alex\Scripts\Bin" & EXIT /B

...
```

Comment: Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not terrible as it is, but you're right to wonder if there's a better way.  As you noticed already, it would be nice to keep the associations between the abbreviation and the corresponding directory in one place.

Fortunately, there's a very slick way to to that.  First, create a text file file that contains just the file associations:

## e.txt

```
db      D:\Alex\Dropbox
bin     D:\Alex\Scripts\Bin
```

## e.cmd

```
@echo off
FOR /F "tokens=1,2" %%i in (e.txt) do if "%~1" EQU "%%i" ( explorer "%%j" & EXIT /B )
ECHO Invalid target %target%.
```

This uses a relatively obscure feature of the `FOR` command that allows us to parse a file.  You can read more about that by executing `HELP FOR` from the command line.

Naturally, in the real version, you'd want to specify the full path to the `e.txt` file.

### Allowing spaces in directory names

If you might have spaces in the directory names, you can do so with little additional effort.  For example, we can use `=` for the delimiter in the text file so that each line now looks like this:

```
sp=D:\Alex\Scripts\Advanced Scripting
```

Now just modify the script so that we specify the delimiter.  To do that change the part of the line that says `"tokens=1,2"` to read `"tokens=1,2 delims=="` and that's it.

Comment: This is great, thanks.
I can even make the script parse itself if I come up with something like

REM [mnemonic] [folder]

Comment: If you choose to have it all in one file, you can use skip=4 to skip over the code lines.